# Error while using ERC-20 java library: "only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC"

Tags: erc-20, web3j, java

I am trying to make simple transaction using ERC-20 java library. I use mumbai test network for polygon. Code transfers stablecoin from one wallet from another. During approve method call I get following error:

"Error processing transaction request: only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC"

When I use rinkeby test network for ethereum and I do same stablecoin transaction it works as expected.

Is it possible to integrate replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions using ERC-20 java library, that will work for both cases (ethereum and polygon)?

```
        String network = "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/";
        String contractAddress = "0xE10a59f3dAAe01e0544E3d45F5579C3eBb7e9c9D";
        String custumerPk = "private key";
        String bridgePk = "private key";
        String bridgeWallet = "0x9d7Be2E6d684Aa8A5995Fe322fF425E9Bdbd6BE7";
        String customerWallet = "0x515e34F4760c7fdcd61d9cAa278f80C15AC7ECdB";

        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(networkPoly));
        Credentials bridgeCreds = Credentials.create(bridgePk);
        ERC20 bridgeToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress ,web3j,bridgeCreds,new DefaultGasProvider());
        Credentials cutromerCreds = Credentials.create(custoerPk);

        ERC20 cutomerToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress ,web3j,cutromerCreds, new DefaultGasProvider());

        BigInteger amount = new BigInteger("1000000000000000000");

        TransactionReceipt send = cutomerToken.approve(bridgeWallet, amount).send();

        TransactionReceipt send1 = bridgeToken.transferFrom(customerWallet, bridgeWallet, amount).send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the chainId. this is required after the London Fork, otherwise the tx will not be accepted.

one way to do that is to define a transaction manager, there are many types of transaction managers in Web3j this is 'only' an example:

```
long chainIdOfPolygon = 80001;
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(networkPoly));

Credentials bridgeCreds = Credentials.create(bridgePk);
TransactionManager bridgeTokenTxManager = new RawTransactionManager(
    web3j, bridgeCreds, chainIdOfPolygon);
ERC20 bridgeToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress, web3j, bridgeTokenTxManager, new DefaultGasProvider());

Credentials cutromerCreds = Credentials.create(custoerPk);
TransactionManager cutomerTokenTxManager = new RawTransactionManager(
    web3j, cutromerCreds, chainIdOfPolygon);
ERC20 cutomerToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress, web3j , cutomerTokenTxManager, new DefaultGasProvider());
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine in my case

Comment: @TornikeMaridashvili please make sure you are using the tx manager that fit your needs there are ClientTransactionManager, RawTransactionManager, ReadonlyTransactionManager